# Angular Material layout column for large display but row for smaller

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I'm trying to have 2 columns side-by-side for a large display, and have a row for anything smaller..

I thought this JSFiddle would work: https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1637/ but it doesn't...

How can you get the `md-card` to be under each other for medium-xs displays but be next to each other for larger displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss to change the layout of the container from `row` to `column` when the display gets smaller.

Here a simple js forked from yours which does what you want to, then choose the flex and the screen sizes you prefer:

https://jsfiddle.net/vtzk6bL0/

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Worked perfectly.